# how do I set the external encoding for pry

Tags: ruby, irb, pry

IRB has the -E flag for setting the external encoding but it doesn't work in pry:

> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pry-0.9.10/lib/pry/repl_file_loader.rb:16:in
>   `initialize': No such file: /Volumes/fb1 store/fb1 10.5
>   user/Users/rashid/Ruby_Dev/MDBlib/src/MDB/-Eutf-8 (RuntimeError)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at this thread: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211133/get-pry-to-display-characters-like-aoussaouss-utf-8-encoding-possibly-window/17456323#17456323][1]. I think this is the same problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211133/get-pry-to-display-characters-like-aoussaouss-utf-8-encoding-possibly-window/17456323#17456323

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of a hack, but I think this should work for you:

```
$ pry -e "#encoding: utf-8"
```

Comment: This does not work for me:

$ pry -e "#coding: us-ascii"
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> Encoding.default_external
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>

$ irb -Eus-ascii
irb(main):001:0> Encoding.default_external
=> #<Encoding:US-ASCII>

Answer (score 0):

put to `~/.pryrc`

```
$stdout.set_encoding 'US-ASCII'
```

to specify your default external encoding

**AND** put to `~/.pryrc` to add pry command `set_encoding` to dinamically change external_encoding.

```
Pry::Commands.create_command "set_encoding" do
  description "Set $stdout.external_encoding to ARGS[0] || 'US-ASCII'"

  def process
    output.set_encoding args[0] || 'UTF-8'
  end
end
```

Use it as

`[1] pry(main)> set_encoding UTF-8`

or to set it back to US-ASCII

`[1] pry(main)> set_encoding`

Comment: unfortunately it still crashes