# Get pry to display characters like [äöüßÄÖÜß] (utf-8 encoding)? (Possibly Windows-specific issue?)

Tags: ruby, windows, utf-8, character-encoding, pry

[*All the scripts I'm working with with these German characters are in UTF-8 themselves, have `#encoding: utf-8` at the top (and `Encoding.external_default = 'utf-8'`, not that that's really relevant I think because German chars in strings that are defined* within *the script don't get displayed right.)*]

All these things display fine at the windows command prompt and using irb etc.

I can't even *enter* these characters at the pry prompt, though. Attempting to paste in `puts "äöüÄÖÜß"` gets `puts "`. Attempting to actually type them *freezes* pry somehow, and I have to ^D out.

Using pry, I ran a script with `GC = "äöüÄÖÜß"` in it, and this is the kind of garbledeegook I get:

```
[1] pry(main)> GC                               
=> "├ñ├Â├╝├ä├û├£├ƒ"                             
[2] pry(main)> GC.split('').each{ |c| puts c }  
├ñ                                              
├Â                                              
├╝                                              
├ä                                              
├û                                              
├£                                              
├ƒ                                              
=> ["├ñ", "├Â", "├╝", "├ä", "├û", "├£", "├ƒ"]
[3] pry(main)> File.open("output.txt", 'w'){|f| GC.split('').each{ |c| f.puts c } }
```

The test file `output.txt` created by that last line, however, *is* in utf-8 and reads:

```
ä
ö
ü
Ä
Ö
Ü
ß
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I know that if you install `Ruby` with `readline` support, then you doesn't have this problem. To do so you will need something like this if you are using `rbenv` (with ruby-build):

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-readline-dir=`brew --prefix readline`" rbenv install 1.9.3
```

I don't know if there are other solutions though.